# Login script not working on live server

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have built an admin section on my localhost for a site i have been working on for a while, everything works as it should on my localhost, but when I have uploaded it to a live server, it just wont work - and when i say wont work, it wont do anything! the login page loads as it should, and if i try to access the index.php page without being logged in, it redirects me to login.php, as it should, but when I go to login, it just reloads the login page, and it does the same when I go to register.

I've spent the whole day going through every possible error I can think of, I've double and then triple checked the database connection, the tables etc, the php, I've echoed "hello world!" from various files included in the login page to see if it was connecting to them properly, and it works everytime... I've even checked the time the server was set to, as I read somewhere on another forum that someone was having a similar issue, they updated the server to the correct time, and it worked, something to do with the session... but alas, nothing seems to work. As I mentioned before, it works perfectly well on my localhost, and I have already tried the login before on a live server which worked, but since then I have done more work.

for reference, here is my class for login / registration etc:

```
<?php

class USER {
private $db_user;

function __construct($db) {
    $this->db_user = $db;
}

public function register($clientID,$u_fname,$u_lname,$u_tel,$u_email,$uname,$upass,$secQuestion,$secAnswer) {

    try {

        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->db_user->prepare("INSERT INTO users(client_id,user,pass,first_name,last_name,telephone,email,sec_question,sec_answer) VALUES(:client,:user, :pass, :fname, :lname, :tel, :email, :secQ, :secA)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":user", $uname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":client", $clientID);
       $stmt->bindparam(":pass", $new_password);
       $stmt->bindparam(":email", $u_email);
       $stmt->bindparam(":fname", $u_fname);
       $stmt->bindparam(":lname", $u_lname);
       $stmt->bindparam(":tel", $u_tel);
       $stmt->bindparam(":secQ", $secQuestion);
       $stmt->bindparam(":secA", $secAnswer);          
       $stmt->execute();

       return $stmt;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function login($uname, $upass) {

    try {

        $stmt = $this->db_user->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=:user LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array(':user'=>$uname));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['pass'])) {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['id'];
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function is_loggedin() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
        return true;
    }
}

public function logout() {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
    return true;
}
}
?>
```

my config file:

```
<?php 

require('constants.php');

try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Could not connect to the database because: " . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

include_once 'class.user.php';
$user = new USER($db);
?>
```

and my login page itself:

```
<?php
session_start();
$page_title = "Love Deals Login";
require('../inc/connect/config.php');


if($user->is_loggedin()!="") {
header("Location: index.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
$uname = $_POST['txt_uname'];
$upass = $_POST['txt_upass'];

if($user->login($uname,$upass)) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $error = "Login failed. Please try again, or register";
}
}

include('inc/admin-header.php');

?>

<div class="container" style="padding: 100px 0 0 0;">
<div class="form-container">
    <form method="post" id="login">
        <h3>Please login</h3>
        <?php if(isset($error)) { ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else if(isset($_GET['joined'])) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> &nbsp; Thanks! You are now registered. You may now login below
                </div>
        <?php } else if(isset($_GET['pass-update'])) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> &nbsp; Success! Your password has been updated. You may now login below
                </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_uname" placeholder="Username" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txt_upass" placeholder="Password" required />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 login">
            <p class="small text">Forgotten <a href="forgot-user.php">Username</a> / <a href="forgot-pass.php">Password?</a></p>
            <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>&nbsp;Login</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3" style="text-align: center;">
            <label>Don't have an account yet? <a href="agree.php">Register now</a></label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<?php include('inc/admin-footer.php'); ?>
```

any ideas what could be preventing my script from running? Or even just point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'll also add that if i deliberately login with an incorrect username or password, it doesn't display the $error message, which it does on localhost...

Comment: Have you checked the error log on the server?

Comment: Yes there are no errors relating to the login page, the only errors were from a server 500 error which I already rectified, which was due to permissions on a separate file...

Comment: One check is weird.  `if ($user->is_loggedin() != "")`. That function returns `true` if the user is logged in, so it will redirect to index if the user is logged in. (`true` is not equal to an empty string).

Comment: yes that was intentional, if they are already logged in they can just be redirected to the index page, i'm yet to write into my script a session timeout...

Comment: Wait? It works on local and not the remote? I'd find out what the differences are there first to see what's going on. Could be, different types of servers, or more likely, the php version is different which is causing an issue.

Comment: the phpmyadmin is an older version on the live server... would that affect it? the reason I've not checked that is because its connecting to the database fine, and pulling in other data for other pages no problem... I'll check the php versions but i'm pretty certain I've checked those previously...

Comment: ok localhost is using php version 5.6.15, and live server is using 5.6.13... can't be massively different can they?

Comment: No, if it was 5.6 and 7, i'd say yes, but a minor change like that...... Without seeing a change log, id have to say that couldn't be the issue. It would be worth your while to update, for security though.

Comment: Did you change the database/table name? On either side and forget to update the file/call? I've done that one before by accident.

Comment: nope, the db name and table name are all correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try !empty() instead of isset() .